# $R^\infty$ is separable

Tags: general-topology

This question is from Introduction to Topology and Modern Analysis by Simmons.

Question:
It has to be proven that $R^\infty$ is separable where $R^\infty$ is defined as follows. The set of all sequences $x=\{x_1,x_2,..,x_n,..\}$ of real numbers, such that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x|^2$ converges is denoted by $R^\infty$.

My thoughts: 
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x|^2$ will converge only if it can approximated by N number of terms for some integer N. So each point can be approximated by $max(N)$ terms. The set of rational numbers is dense in $R$. We can approximate the points in $R^\infty$ by 
at-most N rational numbers. So we can say that $R^\infty$ is separable.

I am not sure weather I am thinking on correct lines and how to express it. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's your topology? Do you use product topology?

Comment: Yes its a product topology

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume you are using product topology, then consider a countable dense subset in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ defined as all points $(x_n)$ such that there is some $m\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_k = 0$ for $k>m$, and $x_1,...,x_m \in \mathbb{Q}$. Hence $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is separable.